# Display other values when the date parameter is null

Tags: jasper-reports

I had a report that needs to display the user-inputed parameters (includes: Data parameters). However, the user can fill nothing in these data parameters.

I had used the textfield to display the user-inputed parameters. When the date parameters are filled values, the report can show it out.

However, I found that if I fill nothing in the data parameters, the report will display the current date in here.

I would like to ask how to modify it to display the "hyphen" rather than displaying the current date.

The data parameter setting is: SDate (java.util.Date, use as a prompt).